# "No network devices available" Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, ethernet, network-drive

I'm new to the Ubuntu community, so please, give a step-by-step answer if possible.

Everything was fine, until my battery became critically low and my computer turned off. After charging and turning back on, my wifi doesn't work.

On the WiFi icon, "Enable Networking" is checked out, but Everytime I selected that option, the message "Disconnected -you are now offline" pops up.

The command line : 
`lspci | grep -i wireless` gives this message:

```
02:00.0 Network controller : Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless network adapter (rev 01)
```

And the command line 
`iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Also, I tried to connect via cable and got no response as well.

EDIT

Here it is: 
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10844622/

thanks for helping me helping you help me!
hahaha

Comment: Run the wireless script found in the answer by Wild Man to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos Then upload the output to pastebin and [edit] your question to provide a link, or if you prefer not running a script, take a look at the sample output and [edit] your question with the results from your system. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Ok, the link is there!

Comment: You have wireless device but it's not recognized by iwconfig. Most likely drivers issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get an Atheros AR9485 wireless card working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240234/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar9485-wireless-card-working)